# Why can't I select a control in the design view of the Android Studio code window?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm following the tutorial [Writing your first Android app – everything you need to know](http://www.androidauthority.com/first-android-app-what-you-need-to-know-619260/), and the 'coding' part essentially starts when the author tells you to select the default "Hello World" `TextView`, at the top left of the design view, and change its position and text. I have done this before, and I know there is supposed to be green frame drawn around the `TextView` when you click it. In fact, when I select the XML in the text view for the `TextView`, a green frame is indeed drawn around it, but I can't move it or find the "Properties" pane for it.

Why can't I select it in the design view? The tutorial goes on to change its position and content, but I cannot proceed until I can select it.

Strangely enough, there is a `FloatingActionButton` at the bottom right of the design view that I can select just as expected.

**NOTE:** This has something to do with the theme. I changed the theme, and was able to select and move the `TextView`. However, I don't remember which theme, and when I closed and re-opened the project, this were back to normal, and I could only select the `FloatingActionButton`. Then, I tried a few other themes, and now I can't even select the button.

Comment: what APi are you using, maybe it only works with the latest

Comment: The `FloatingActionButton` is introduced with Lollipop. May be you are following an older tutorial.

Comment: The tutorial says to use `API 15: Android 4.0.3`, and I have done this before, a year or so ago, and had no problems.

Comment: @JayMayu But I don't have a problem with the `FloatingActionButton`, and I'm sure the humble `TextView` has been around a while. I have edited my question to make it clear that it's a `TextView` being used, not a label.

Comment: It could be possible that selection style is changed in new version of Android Studio. Check the Studio version in the tutorial you're following and the one you're using.